# Where should XDG_CACHE_HOME be set on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04, xdg

According to [the specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html):

> `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` defines the base directory relative to which user-specific non-essential data files should be stored. If `$XDG_CACHE_HOME` is either not set or empty, a default equal to `$HOME/.cache` should be used.

Where/when should I set this envvar?

Comment: You can add it in `~/.bash_profile` for example

Comment: @RomeoNinov Will that affect only inside terminals running the bash shell or also if I start the browser from the desktop (gnome/wayland)?

Comment: Not sure about desktop environment.